# Как получить id первого дочерного элемента

Tags: javascript

как получить id первого дочерного элемента, например в коде ниже имеется обвёртка slide_block, как получить id первого (именно первого) вложенного блока, далее этот узел будет удалён и при вызове функции повторно нужно получить id следующего блока который встанет вместо первого, заранее спасибо.

```
<div class="slide_block">
    <div class="slide" id="slide_1"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_5"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.slide_block').children[0].id);
```

```html
<div class="slide_block">
    <div class="slide" id="slide_1"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_5"></div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_6"></div>
</div>
```

---

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function(e) {
  document.querySelector('.slide_block').children[0].remove();
}
```

```html
<button>Remove first</button>

<div class="slide_block">
    <div class="slide" id="slide_1">1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_2">2</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_3">3</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_4">4</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_5">5</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide_6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как найти самый последний узел

Comment: @иосифмахарадзе, `children.length - 1`